# How do I create a string of blanks in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I need to create a string of blanks in c++, where the number of spaces is a variable, so I can't just type it in. 
How do I do this without looping ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

```
size_t size = 5; // size_t is similar to unsigned int ‡
std::string blanks(size, ' ');
```

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

‡ See the question on [size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t) if this isn't clear.

Comment: What if I want to pass the number of spaces as a parameter

Comment: 5 can be replaced by a variable.

Comment: I wouldn't refer to the foot-note using `*` - it looks like a pointer ;)

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche, I changed it to a double dagger, but there's not much I can do without being able to superscript it :(

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted more often compared to the one provided by cape1232? His way looks more clean to me.

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <string>
std::string mystring(5,' ');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <string>
.....
//i is your variable length
string s_blanks_length_i( i, ' ' );
```

Answer (score 5):

5 spaces to standard output:

```
std::cout << std::string( 5, ' ' ) << std::endl;
```