# Point of size_t

Tags: c++, types, size-t

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unsigned int vs. size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t)

When I need to store the size of something (usually stuff allocated with `new`), I always store it in an `unsigned int`.  Browsing through some code, however, I saw `size_t` used.  According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/size_t/), it's hardly used for a lot.

- What is the point of `size_t` in C++?
- Why don't those few functions that use it just use an `unsigned int` instead?
- How should it be used in new code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unsigned int vs. size_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t) - pretty definitive info there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have an array, the size and indexing of which can exceed the range of an int, as an int is only guaranteed 16bits. The practicality of using size_t is rather low right now but may become more important in the future. On MSVC compiling for 64bit, for example, I could have a class, an instance of which is larger than 4GB. Of course, I expect that in practicality, the CRT won't deal with sizes that large, but the Standard is unconcerned with that.