# What are the potential security vulnerabilities? C++

Tags: c++, security, code-access-security

My boss told me to look at the following code and tell him what the potential security vulnerabilities were. I'm not very good at this kind of thing, since I don't think in the way of trying to hack code. All I see is that nothing is declared private, but other than that I just don't know.

```
#define NAME_SIZE (unsigned char) 255
// user input should contain the user’s name (first name space
// middle initial space last name and a null
// character), and was entered directly by the user.
// Returns the first character in the user input, or -1 if the method failed.
char poor_method(char* user_input, char* first, char *middle, char* last)
{
   char*buffer;
   char length;

   // find first name
   buffer = strtok(user_input, " ");
   if(buffer==0)
   {
        return -1;
   }
   length = strlen(buffer);
   if(length <= NAME_SIZE)
   {
        strcpy(first, buffer);
   }

   // find middle name
   buffer = strtok(NULL, " ");
   if(buffer==0)
   {
        return-1;
   }
   if(middle)
       *middle = buffer[0];

   // find last name
   buffer = strtok(NULL, "\0");
   length = strlen(buffer);
   if(length <= NAME_SIZE)
   {
       strcpy(last, buffer);
   }
   // Check to make sure that all of the user input was used
   buffer = strtok(NULL, "\0");
   if(buffer != NULL)
   {
       return-1;
   }
   return first[0];
}
```

What security vulnerabilities are there?

Comment: Just throw it away and write it in a proper C++ way. strtok is not thread-safe, for starters.

Comment: I hope your boss is not on SO. ;) By "security" it seems you think it relates to hacking. Can he not simply mean memory issues, wrongly formatted input, etc. Perhaps that might be less out of your comfort zone?

Comment: @Bart Maybe he does. I just assume hacking when I hear security. I'll look at it in this way!

Comment: strtok, depending on the C-runtime, is thread-safe.

Comment: Look up [Buffer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Also you can search on [ITsec.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I saw (by no means a complete list):

1. There's no guarantees you're going to get a char pointer which points to a null-terminating string (unless you're allowed to make that assumption, not really a safe one to make).
2. strtok and strcpy are the C way of doing things and come with the fun stuff of programming C code. If you must use them, so be it (just make sure you can guarantee you're inputs to these functions will indeed be valid). Otherwise, try switching your code to use `std::string` and the "C++ way" (as Cat Plus Plus put it)
3. I'm assuming this is a typo:

   ```
   charpoor_method(
   ```

   You're missing a space between `char` and `poor_method(`
4. You're not checking if `first` or `last` are indeed valid pointers (unfortunately, the best you can do is to check them against `NULL`).
5. There's no guarantee that the buffers `first` or `last` can indeed hold whatever you're copying to them.
6. Another typo:

```
returnfirst[0];
```

missing space between `return` and `first[0]`

Learning to write secure code is something that's very important to do. Follow Brecht's advice and get good at it.

Answer (score 6):

**Get good at writing secure code**

You most likely *don't* want systems that you are responsible for finding their way onto [bugtraq](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1) or [cve](http://cve.mitre.org/). If you don't understand it, be honest with your boss. Tell him you don't understand and you want to work on it. Pick up [Writing Secure Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735617228). Read it, learn it, love it. Asking this question on SO and giving your boss the answer definitely doesn't help you in the long run.

*Then* look at the sample code again :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Ok strtok assumes user_input is NULL terminated, this might not be true.

```
 charlength = strlen(buffer);
  if(length <= NAME_SIZE)
  {
        strcpy(first, buffer);
  }
```

1. charlenght here is undeclared, so is length, they should be declared as unsigned int.
2. strlen wont count the '\0' as a part of the length, so later strcpy will copy the '\0' to whatever is after First if the len of buffer is 255 + 1('\0')
3. Also is unknown if char *first size is, it should be NAME_SIZE but the comparisson should be
   length <= NAME_SIZE - 1
   or allocate char *first to NAME_SIZE + 1

I'd probably rewrite the whole thing, is quite ugly.

Comment: Shouldn't `charlength` be a `size_t`?

Comment: Yeah, size_t is typedef as unsigned int

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t "[size_t] may be bigger, equal or even smaller than an unsigned int and your compiler might make assumption about it for optimization purpose."

Comment: It's what he showed me. I'm assuming it's written horribly just for the purpose of teaching new hires.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `strcpy()`, use `strncpy()` with a specific length parameter, as that function, like `strtok()`, assumes a NULL-terminated buffer for the source, and that may not be the case, giving you a buffer overflow for the data copied into the buffer pointed to by either `first` or `last`.   Additionally, you have no idea how long the buffers are that have been allocated for `first` and `last` ... Don't assume that the user of your function has properly allocated enough memory to copy into unless they've passed you a parameter telling you there are enough memory slots in the buffers.  Otherwise again, you could (and most likely will) end-up with buffer overflows.

Also you may want to use the `restrict` keyword if you're using C99 in order to prevent the caller of your function from aliasing the same memory location for `buffer`, `first`, and `last`.