# finding security vulnerabilities in millions of lines of code

Tags: c++, c, security

I saw an interview question on how would you go on finding security vulnerabilities in million lines of code. What intrigues me is that the term "security vulnerabilities" is very broad. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890112/what-are-the-potential-security-vulnerabilities-c) but its a very small code here.

As I just googled out, I got some hits for static code analysis tools. But I wasn't satisfied with this. I feel there might some other better tools out there.

Can someone tell me what all  can be classified as security vulnerability (like memory leak, race conditions, etc.) and what are the tools used by software companies for such issues?

I saw this post in a C/C++ programming forum so any replies related to C/C++ would be more helpful, nonetheless it is definitely helpful even if it is pertaining to other than C/C++.

Comment: Penetration testing, fuzz testing, fault injection, code reviews...

Comment: That's helpful.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The blunt, honest response would have been to question the effectiveness and feasibility of *finding security vulnerabilities* at *identifying problematic code to be fixed*. It's not a 100% accurate task unless you test the code for all possible C implementations, because a *vulnerability* on one implementation or at one particular time may not be on another; There are an infinite number of effects undefined behaviour can have.