# C++ vector size types

Tags: c++, vector, int

I just started learning C++ and have a question about vectors.
The book I'm reading states that if I want to extract the size of a vector of type double (for example), I should do something like:

```
vector<double>::size_type vector_size;
vector_size = myVector.size();
```

Whereas in Java I might do

```
int vector_size;
vector_size = myVector.size();
```

My question is, why is there a type named vector::size_type? Why doesn't C++ just use int?

Comment: There are answers in this question [http://stackoverflow.com/q/131803/72178](http://stackoverflow.com/q/131803/72178).

Comment: In C++11, you can say `auto vector_size = myVector.size();` and worry a little less ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow That's no good if you're initializing `vector_size` to `0` but you intend to use it as a `vector<double>::size_type`.

Comment: @BrianGordon I don't understand your objection. If `myVector` is of type `std::vector<double>`, and you write `auto vector_size = myVector.size();` then `vector_size` is of type `std::vector<double>::size_type`, no matter if the vector is empty or not. Please clarify.

Comment: If you have `for(std::vector<double>::size_type i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++)` then auto cannot be used to declare `i`.

Comment: To add to the comments and answers, `int` may simply not be large enough. In my current project I have a vector with far more than 4.2E9 entries. `int` ranges only from -2.1E9 to 2.1E9. Even `unsigned int` would be too small

Comment: On 64 bit is possible that the size of the vector is larger than 2GB. That's why.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

C++ is a language for library writing*, and allowing the author to be as general as possible is one of its key strengths. Rather than prescribing the standard containers to use any particular data type, the more general approach is to decree that each container expose a `size_type` member type. This allows for greater flexibility and genericity. For example, consider this generic code:

```
template <template <typename...> Container, typename T>
void doStuff(const Container<T> & c)
{
  typename Container<T>::size_type n = c.size();
  // ...
}
```

This code will work on *any* container template (that can be instantiated with a single argument), and we don't impose any unnecessary restrictions on the user of our code.

(In practice, most size types will resolve to `std::size_t`, which in turn is an unsigned type, usually `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` -- but why should we have to know that?)

<sub>*) I'm not sure what the corresponding statement for Java would be.</sub>

Comment: @Kerrek Unless you are on a 64 bit system where `std::size_t` is probably a 64 bit type.

Comment: @xanatos: that's true. Maybe we should dig up some of the common typedefs, out of curiosity.

Comment: this does not compile with C++20

Comment: To make this compile, first line should be:
`template<template<typename...> typename Container, typename T>`

Answer (score 6):

Java does not have unsigned integer types, so they have to go with `int`.

Contrarily, C++ does and uses them where appropriate (where negative values are nonsensical), the canonical example being the length of something like an array.

Comment: The reason why the standard uses `size_t`, rather than `int`, is because on some smaller machines, `int` wouldn't have been large enough (and going to `long` would have incurred a performance penalty).  The use of an unsigned type here is generally recognized as a flaw, since unsigned types in C and C++ work in somewhat funny ways.  (Basically, an expression like `abs(i1 - i2)` should correctly give the distance between two index types.  It doesn't if `i1` or `i2` are unsigned.)

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard says that a container's `size_type` is an unsigned integral type, but it doesn't specify which one; one implementation might use `unsigned int` and another might use `unsigned long`, for example.

C++ isn't "shielded" from platform-specific implementation details as much as Java is.  The `size_type` alias helps to shield *your* code from such details, so it'll work properly regardless of what actual type should be used to represent a vector's size.

Answer (score 2):

My personal feeling about this is that it is for a better code safety/readability.

For me `int` is a type which conveys no special meaning: it can number apples, bananas, or anything.

`size_type`, which is probably a `typedef` for `size_t` has a stronger meaning: it indicates a size, in bytes.

That is, it is easier to know what a variable mean. Of course, following this rationale, there could be a lot of different types for different units. But a "buffer size" is really a common case so it somehow deserves a dedicated type.

Another aspect is code maintability: if the container suddenly changes its `size_type` from say, `uint64_t` to `unsigned int` for instance, using `size_type` you don't have to change it in every source code relying on it.

Answer (score 2):

The book you’re reading states that if you want to extract the size of a vector of type double (for example), you should do something like:

```
    vector<double>::size_type vector_size;
    vector_size = myVector.size();
```

Whereas in Java you might do

```
    int vector_size;
    vector_size = myVector.size();
```

Both are inferior options in C++. The first is extremely verbose and unsafe (mostly due to implicit promotions). The second is verbose and extremely unsafe (due to number range).

In C++, do

```
    ptrdiff_t const vectorSize = myVector.size();
```

Note that

- `ptrdiff_t`, from the `stddef.h` header, is a signed type that is guaranteed large enough.
- Initialization is done in the declaration (this is better C++ style).
- The *same* naming convention has been applied to both variables.

In summary, doing the right thing is shorter and safer.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the first method is unsafe. What do you mean by implicit promotions?

Comment: Unless they've fixed it in C++11, `ptrdiff_t` is **not** guaranteed to be large enough.  It's possible to have objects the size of which cannot be represented in a `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @James: there's not room enough here to discuss how an array of `char` might be too large in a 16-bit address space. the answer for a 3 GiB array of `char` in 32-bit address space is that it's not supported by the standard (`ptrdiff_t` is required to be large enough), so deal specially with it if you must have that beast. Personally, I have never encountered the 3 GiB array of `char`. :-)

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach I've never needed a 3 GiB array of `char` either, but 
I've used 32 bit implementations which supported them (Sun CC under
Solaris, g++ under Linux on a 32 bit PC).  The C standard definitely
allows pointer subtraction to overflow (resulting in undefined
behavior), and as far as I know, the C++ standard just passes the buck
on to the C standard here.

Comment: @James: there seems to me to be a dispute here between 5.7 and 18.2 in C++11. 5.7 says that overflow is possible, 18.2 says that `ptrdiff_t` "can hold the difference of two subscripts in an array object, as described in 5.7". This is different from the text in C89/C99, which just says that `ptrdiff_t` is the type of the result of pointer subtraction, not that it can in general hold the value. It reads to me as if whoever wrote it was expecting the issue to be resolved in C++11, but there's still a difference in language between 18.2/6 (big enough for *any* object) and /5 (*an* array object).

Comment: They *could* have said explicitly in 18.2/5 that `ptrdiff_t` is big enough to hold the result of any valid pointer/index subtraction, and removed the text about overflow in 5.7. They chose not to. I don't see how this decision can be interpreted to mean anything other than that `ptrdiff_t` is *not* guaranteed big enough as James says, but it's possible that the committee has the non-obvious meaning in mind, or that there's text elsewhere that helps.

Comment: @Steve: the only reasonable interpretation is that *an* means *any*, because otherwise it refers to some specific array object that might be one byte for all we know, and then the statement is *meaningless* (imposes no contraints and imparts no new information).

Comment: @SteveJessop The difference between C and C++ is interesting; I would
have expected the C++ standard to simply say that these types are
defined as in C.  I'd be inclined to agree with Alf, that the only
reasonable interpretation of "in an array object" is "in any array
object", except that §5.7/6 clearly and explicitly says the opposite.  I
sort of think that a DR is in order.  (I also know that a certain number
of the committee would strongly oppose any difference with C here.  It
would be highly undesirable that `ptrdiff_t` be different types in C and
in C++.)

Comment: @Alf: I'd agree, except that 18.2/5 *immediately* backs off from that by saying "as described in 5.7", which explicitly describes the possibility of `ptrdiff_t` being too small. When different language is used in adjacent paragraphs, I'm inclined to read that as significant, with different meaning intended, so in this case "an" != "any" . I would not even be surprised if the committee is divided on the issue, with some genuinely believing that they've fixed it and others genuinely believing that they've retained consistency with C. I suppose one would have to check the minutes.

Comment: @James: certainly there's a flaw - either text in 5.7 is redundant (and is misleading you and me) since in fact `ptrdiff_t` is big enough and overflow is impossible, or else that text isn't redundant and 18.2/5 is misleading Alf since in fact it just means "this is the type of an offset in an array", not "this type can represents all offsets in all arrays". Since the answer to the question affects how people write quite simple code (specifically - a lot of people want to avoid unsigned types, so a signed type that holds sizes is very useful), it does matter.

Comment: @SteveJessop To add to what has been said already: existing practice says that `ptrdiff_t` can overflow.  It certainly could on all of the 16 bit machines I used, and it can with g++ under Linux and Sun CC under Solaris.  (I suspect that in all such cases, the compiler authors simply thought that C++ was compatible with C here, and did what they'd done in C.)

Comment: @James: since nobody claims to fully support C++11 yet anyway, I wonder if any of them has on their unimplemented feature lists, "stick a wrapper around system memory allocation to prevent it returning a block bigger than ptrdiff_t can hold", referencing the text of 18.2/5 as a new requirement.

Comment: @SteveJessop I hadn't noticed that that §18.2 (which was §18.1) had
changed in C++11; §18.1 in C++03 says about what I expected (i.e. it
forwards to C).  Since this is clearly a change, it makes me think that
the intent was to require `ptrdiff_t` to be big enough to not overflow
(which means making it `long long` on most 32 bit machines), and that
nobody noticed the discrepancy in §5.7.  I'll raise a DR tonight (if I
remember).

Comment: @James: But as you said earlier, it needs to be consistent with C. If you're following an ABI in which `ptrdiff_t` is already defined to be 32-bit on a 32-bit machine, you can't change it to `long long` (i.e. a breaking change in the C ABI) just for C++11. So if that was the intent of the author, it won't work. Instead you need to cripple `malloc` to prevent 2GB allocations (presuming that it previously allowed them), and come to think of it you need to cripple it in C too, to prevent C code from passing jumbo arrays to C++ code.

Comment: @Steve: I think the C requirement of at least 17 bits `ptrdiff_t` (not 16 bits but 17, implied by required value range) indicates that in C the intent is for `ptrdiff_t` to be large enough, with resolution of the conflict on 16-bit architecture in favor of large `ptrdiff_t` or special compiler support, instead of crippling `malloc`.

Comment: @SteveJessop That would be the other solution, but it would break existing code as well.  (I've got one C++ program under Linux which does a `new char[0x80000000]`.  That would break.)  I don't think the vendors will go along with crippling `malloc` and `new`, and I don't think they'll go along with breaking their public API (and Posix, at least, uses `ptrdiff_t` in its API).  Which means that whatever the committee really intended, nothing will actually change.

Comment: @Alf: yes, I think it's only 32-bit architectures where there's confusion, arguably whoever designed the C ABIs should have done something different -- just because the C standard permits overflow doesn't mean they should necessarily have taken advantage of that to make `ptrdiff_t` 32 bits wide. On 64-bit architectures `malloc` is naturally crippled so the issue doesn't arise there either, `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` can be the same size, at least until someone wants a 2^63 byte array backed by sparse storage.