# What determines how much memory can be allocated?

Tags: c, memory-management, size-t

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) about why size_t is necessary.

Given that size_t is guaranteed to be big enough to represent the largest size of a block of memory you can allocate (meaning there can still be some integers bigger than size_t), my question is...

What determines how much you can allocate at once?

Comment: Look at the correction I have done to your question

Comment: The OS. these are just some extra characters because the comment wasn't long enough.

Comment: @xanatos So size_t can actually be bigger than it's necessary for it to be?

Comment: @Paul Yes. As I've said in the other post, on Windows Server 2008 R2 you can't really allocate 64 bits of memory (in the same way you can't allocate 4 gb of memory on Windows 32 bits), still the `size_t` are 64 bits and 32 bits long. They are normally rounded up (often to the word size of the processor, 32 or 64 bits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The architecture of your machine, the operating system (but the two are intertwined) and your compiler/set of libraries determines how much memory you can allocate at once.

`malloc` doesn't **need** to be able to use all the memory the OS could give him. The OS doesn't **need** to make available all the memory present in the machine (and various versions of Windows Server for example have different maximum memory *[for licensing reasons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*)

But note that the OS **can** make available more memory than the one present in the machine, and even more memory than the one permitted by the motherboard (let's say the motherboard has a single memory slot that accepts only 1gb memory stick, Windows could still let a program allocate 2gb of memory). This is done throught the use of Virtual Memory, Paging (you know, the swap file, your old and slow friend :-) Or, for example, through the use of [NUMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access).

Comment: Memory fragmentation also can influence on that value.

Comment: @xappymah Much more complex... Allocation space fragmentation (in protected mode) normally influences much earlier than real memory fragmentation. On a Win 32 with 3 gb of ram, it's impossible to allocate a single block of 2gb, and quite often it's complex to even allocate a single block of 5-700 mb (I know this because I tried to mmap iso of CD)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three constraints, in actual code:

- The biggest unsigned int size_t is able to allocate. size_t should be the same type (same size, etc.) the OS' memory allocation mechanism is using.
- The biggest block the operating system is able to handle in RAM (how are block's size represented? how this representation affects the maximum block size?).
- Memory fragmentation (largest free block) and the total available free RAM.

Comment: `Memory fragmentation (largest free block)` in protected mode it's largest swat of virtual address space available.