# Should I use std::size_t to count instance of my class?

Tags: c++

I have a class:

```
class Nothing
{

    /// Constructor, Destructor, Copy and Assignment
    public:
    Nothing();
    ~Nothing();
    Nothing(const Nothing& clone);

    /// Operators
    const Nothing& operator=(const Nothing& other);

    /// Static Members
    private:
    static unsigned long long id_counter;
    static unsigned long long instance_counter;
};


Nothing::Nothing()
{
    m_name.clear();
    id_counter ++;
    m_id = id_counter;

    instance_counter ++;
}

Nothing::~Nothing()
{
    m_name.clear();
    instance_counter --;
}

Nothing::Nothing(const Nothing& other)
{

}

unsigned long long Nothing::id_counter = 0;
unsigned long long Nothing::instance_counter = 0;
```

Notice I am using unsigned long long to count instances of the class. Should I use std::size_t instead?

As an aside: If I have an instance of a class, and I do something like this:

```
Nothing instance;
instance(Nothing()); // Calling copy constructor
```

Will the destructor be called before the copy constructor is called? Reason for asking is do I need `id_counter ++;` and `instance_counter ++;` inside of my copy constructor?

Comment: You're definitely not calling the copy constructor there. The `instance` is constructed on the first line. The second line will call `operator()` on it.

Comment: Why do you need to count instances of your class?

Comment: And you defenitely need to increment counters in the copy constructor. Because it really create a new instance.

Comment: Still, why call copy constructor with *type* argument? The `instance` is constructed in the first line by the ctor not the copy-ctor.

Comment: @phoeagon: There is no copy constructor "call" here. In fact, `instance(Nothing)` is not valid code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand that. I'm trying to guess what EdwardBird was trying to do and obviously I'm not guessing it correct.

Comment: I am trying to do something like, call the copy constructor with the argument of a different instance of the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::size_t definition is implementation specific, as you can see in [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). In most implementations you will find it is defined as `unsigned int`.

So to answer your question, you can use it instead of `unsigned long long` if you prefer, and your code will remain portable (as long as you don't actually require it to be 64-bit long) in the sense that std::size_t is guaranteed to be defined on every c++ compiler. If the `unsigned long long` requirement is a mandatory (which I doubt since you are using it for instance count) then its best to stick with `unsigned long long`.

> ```
> instance(Nothing); // Calling copy constructor: Should this be `instance(Nothing())`?
> ```

This is bad syntax. If you are trying to invoke the `copy ctor` on a newly formed instance you should call `Nothing copyInstance (Nothing());`. Of course that's a very silly thing to do since you are copying a "clean" instance, you might as well have called `Nothing copyInstance;` to the same effect.

> do I need id_counter ++; and instance_counter ++; inside of my copy constructor?

You should definitely increment instance_counter since you are constructing a new instance. You didn't specify what id_counter counts (reference count??) so it's hard to say.

> Will the destructor be called before the copy constructor is called?

Nowhere in your code do I see a place where the `dtor` will be called but since you are allocating `instance` on the stack, its destructor will be called once `instance` reaches the end of its scope (next `}` appearance).

Comment: The relevance is the effect on portability when using std::size_t but I expanded the answer to clarify

Comment: The question isn't "how portable is `std::size_t`?" It's "should I use `std::size_t` here?"

Comment: "should I use std::size_t here?" doesn't specify concerns for using/not using std::Size_t. I chose to answer with regard to portability because as far as I can tell it's the only concern that could affect whether to use it or not. There is nothing factually wrong with my answer and it addresses the original question's concern so I really don't see the reason for the downvote.

Comment: The question is: `I am using unsigned long long to count instances of the class. Should I use std::size_t instead?` Your answer _is_ better now that you added the paragraph that begins "so to answer your question".

Comment: `Nowhere in your code do I see a place where the dtor will be called `That'd be, when `instance` goes out of scope. Which C++ book are you using, please?

Comment: Oh, the rest of the sentence that totally contradicts the first part of the sentence? Sure I did.

Comment: In the scope of the code the OP gave, no dtor is called. Out of the scope of his code, when instance goes out of scope, its dtor will be called. And that is in so many words, exactly what I said.

Comment: Hah, touché. I'll give you that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, you have managed to cause more problems than solutions here.

Comment: @EdwardBird: I have done nothing but attempt to give _you_ the best and most accurate information that you can get, by identifying misleading and/or inaccurate statements in the comments and answers. As you can see, it led to this answer being _vastly_ improved to the point at which you were able to accept it. You're welcome. Yet again, as you have done elsewhere, you seem very hostile to your free volunteers. In fact it is _your_ comment that adds zero value. I think I shan't be participating on your questions any longer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Please see to it that you do.

Comment: @EdwardBird: And now, just for that, I shall participate in each and every one! See you soon

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit surely this is childish?

Comment: @EdwardBird: I take writing extensively detailed technical answers to SO questions quite seriously; I do not believe that it is childish. However, this comment thread is becoming rather childish, so I'm going to leave you to it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the irony is that you take this too seriously, and yet you are behaving immaturely at the same time.

Comment: @EdwardBird: Fascinating. Do go on.

Answer (score 2):

`std::size_t` is the type of a `sizeof` expression and usually the type returned by `size()` and `capacity()` of the STL containers.  (Technically, the STL containers each typedef a `size_type`, but that's almost always equivalent to `std::size_t`.)

Except for machines with weird memory models (e.g., one that distinguishes between "near" and "far" pointers), a `std::size_t` will always be large enough to count all of the objects that you can fit into memory at one time.  This is not a direct guarantee, but a side-effect of the way the definitions are written.

**Therefore, `std::size_t` is a natural type for things like instance counts.**

Note that `std::size_t` is an unsigned type.  Many people believe you should avoid unsigned types except for representing actual bit patterns (for example, see the [Google Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Integer_Types)).  By using an unsigned type, some arithmetic operations may behave in surprising ways.  If you had a bug that caused your instance count to go negative, it might be hard to detect, because a negative value will wrap around to a very large positive value.

Personally, I find that argument unpersuasive; signed arithmetic also behaves in surprising ways when dealing with overflow and underflow.  Also, when you're trying to use STL types, assigning `size()` to a signed value or comparing a signed value to `size()` requires explicit casts or disabling compiler warnings.  I dislike disabling compiler warnings, especially since they can help you find many of the bugs that people fear when they suggest avoiding unsigned types.

I would used `std::size_t`.  There's nothing wrong with `unsigned long long`, but that might not scale as well with the host platform.

If you want to keep your options open, then you can add a typedef to your Nothing class, which makes it easy to change your mind later:

```
/// Static Members
private:
typedef unsigned long long CounterType;  // consider std::size_t
static CounterType id_counter;
static CounterType instance_counter;
```

You could even call your typedef `size_type` if you want to match the style of the STL containers.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using unsigned long long to count instances of the class. Should I use std::size_t instead?

There's no reason to use `std::size_t` and no reason not to use `std::size_t`. It's a useful type for things like array indices (see: [unsigned int vs. size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t)), but does not correlate at all to the maximum quantity of objects that you can create in any given program. So just choose whichever you like based upon how many objects *you* think you're going to have.

> Will the destructor be called before the copy constructor is called?

You didn't call the copy constructor at all. In fact you can never "call" any constructor. The copy constructor is automatically invoked when you create a new object and initialise it from an existing object, but nowhere in your code do you do that.

> do I need `id_counter ++;` and `instance_counter ++;` inside of my copy constructor?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, both should be okay, at least in the near future.

As is described [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t) and [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/size_t/), `size_t` is the type of the return value of `sizeof()` operator and is guaranteed to hold the size of the largest object possible on the current platform. It's usually `unsigned` also.

And yeah, using `unsigned long long` is unlikely to cause any problem in the near future. Yet `size_t` might gives you an extra advantage when you migrate to, say, 128bit environment, on maximum compatibility.

---

But if your code depends on the fact that `unsigned long long` has *at least* 0~2^64-1 it's probably not a good idea to switch to `size_t`.

---

yes, you need to update the counter in your copy constructor to get it straight.

---

P.S. I don't see why you would want to:

```
Nothing instance; 
instance(Nothing);
```

maybe some member function like `static Nothing Nothing::instance()` to get a new instance? // I just don't see why you would want to call a copy-ctor on a *type* instead of an existing *instance*.

And BTW you can always call `printf()` and `flush()` from constructors and destructors to examine their order of execution.