# Difference between size_t and unsigned int?

Tags: c, types, unsigned

I am so confused about `size_t`. I have searched on the internet and everywhere mentioned that `size_t` is an unsigned type so, it can represent only non-negative values.

My first question is: if it is used to represent only non-negative values, why don't we use `unsigned int` instead of `size_t`?

My second question is: are `size_t` and `unsigned int` interchangeable or not? If not, then why?

And can anyone give me a good example of `size_t` and briefly its workings?

Comment: `typedef /*This part is implementation dependent */ size_t; `

Comment: possible duplicate of [unsigned int vs. size\_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

> if it is use to represent non negative value so why we not using `unsigned int` instead of `size_t`

Because `unsigned int` is not the only unsigned integer type. `size_t` could be any of `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`, depending on the implementation.

> Second question is that `size_t` and `unsigned int` are interchangeable or not and if not then why?

They aren't interchangeable, for the reason explained above `^^`.

> And can anyone give me a good example of size_t and its brief working ?

I don't quite get what you mean by "its brief working". It works like any other unsigned type (in particular, like the type it's typedeffed to). You are encouraged to use `size_t` when you are describing the size of an object. In particular, the `sizeof` operator and various standard library functions, such as `strlen()`, return `size_t`.

Bonus: [here's a good article](https://www.viva64.com/en/a/0050/) about `size_t` (and the closely related `ptrdiff_t` type). It reasons very well why you should use it.

Comment: How exactly can `size_t` be a `unsigned char`? Is this in the standard that it's allowed? I mean with that idea how could anyone be expected to use `calloc()` (and family), `strlen()` etc.? That seems to me absurd.

Comment: I think `size_t` is defined in the standard to be an "unsigned integer type", but doesn't require it to be the same as any of  `unsigned {char, short, int, long, long long}`.

Comment: @Pryftan, for example an 8-bit architecture would use ``unsigned char`` as `size_t`. You don't need to worry about what `size_t` will be, compilers takes care of it depending on the target architecture.

Comment: "the memory size (in bytes) of the size_t is decided by the compiler. The compiler (somehow) determines the most suitable unsigned integer datatype which can hold the largest possible arraysize (of 1 byte/smallest unit of memory) that the architecture/hardware can support and typedef it as **size_t**" - please validate the truthness of my statement.

Answer (score 113):

There are 5 standard unsigned integer types in C:

- `unsigned char`
- `unsigned short`
- `unsigned int`
- `unsigned long`
- `unsigned long long`

with various requirements for their sizes and ranges (briefly, each type's range is a subset of the next type's range, but some of them may have the same range).

`size_t` is a `typedef` (i.e., an alias) for some unsigned type, (probably one of the above but possibly an *extended unsigned integer type*, though that's unlikely). It's the type yielded by the `sizeof` operator.

On one system, it might make sense to use `unsigned int` to represent sizes; on another, it might make more sense to use `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`. (`size_t` is unlikely to be either `unsigned char` or `unsigned short`, but that's permitted).

The purpose of `size_t` is to relieve the programmer from having to worry about *which* of the predefined types is used to represent sizes.

Code that assumes `sizeof` yields an `unsigned int` would not be portable. Code that assumes it yields a `size_t` is more likely to be portable.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because it explains why you should use size_t

Comment: @keith-thompson so does this mean that the specific type (i.e. `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, etc.) that `size_t` corresponds to depends on the machine on which the code is run?  i.e. on one machine architecture, it corresponds to `unsigned int` but on another architecture it will correspond to `unsigned long`, etc?

Comment: @RichieThomas: It depends on the C implementation. Two different compilers on the same architecture might choose different types for `size_t`, especially if, for example, `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` are the same size.

Comment: @RichieThomas That's part of it too. That is to say that the max of `long`, `long long` etc. do depend on the system: If you take a look at `limits.h` you will at least under Unices see that the max value for ints depends on the word size of the system.

Comment: @Pryftan: It's not entirely clear what either "the system" or "word size" really means. For example, on exactly the same hardware, Windows implementations will typically have 32-bit `long` and Unix-like (including Linux-based) implementations will typically have 64-bit `long. x86-64 (x64) systems have a word size of 64 bits, but `int` is almost always 32 bits. All those choices are ultimately up to the C implementation, specifically the compiler. The compiler's choice is likely to be guided by an ABI.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well I didn't know the Windows part but yes you're right - I won't deny that at all. I would also expect `sizeof int == 4` indeed. I don't know what makes the compiler decide but I suspect it's more than just the word size as you say; I am as I noted only speaking on a Unix basis and admittedly it's been decades since I used anything but Linux! I will argue though that word size is clear: it's just how it's used wrt the sizeof integers might not be. Or are you saying that too? Anyway interesting what you say about Windows and all the more relevant to the post! Cheers.

Comment: @Pryftan: `int` has remained 32 bits in most implementations for backward compatibility and to ensure that there are integer types of 8, 16, and 32 bits. Making `char` 8 bits and `int` 64 bits (which would be "natural" on many CPUs) would mean `short` could be either 16 or 32 bits, and there would be no fundamental type of the other size. (C99 introduced *extended integer types*, but they're rarely implemented.) There have been CPUs in which the word size is  unclear, for example in families of CPUs transitioning from 16 to 32 or 32 to 64.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well I didn't know the 'why' wrt portability and I certainly didn't know about specific CPUs that have unclear word sizes. That's interesting. I won't trigger the website here complaining about 'chat' so don't worry about telling me what CPUs - I have too much going on to consider it much anyway. Thanks for the interesting titbits.

Comment: @Pryftan Take a look at the Motorola 68000 series, also the older Intel x86 series (going back to the 8086 and 8088).

Answer (score 12):

`size_t` has a specific restriction.

Quoting from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/size_t/ :

> Alias of one of the fundamental unsigned integer types.
>
> **It is a type able to represent the size of any object in bytes**: size_t is the type returned by the sizeof operator and is widely used in the standard library to represent sizes and counts.

It is not interchangeable with `unsigned int` because the size of `int` is specified by the data model. For example LLP64 uses a 32-bit `int` and ILP64 uses a 64-bit `int`.

Comment: Where is that quotation from? (It's not from the C standard.)

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:c]. The C++ standard has no bearing on C.

Answer (score 11):

Apart from the other answers it also documents the code and tells people that you are talking about size of objects in memory

Comment: Good point. An `apple` is an _apple_, a `size_t` is a _size_...

Answer (score 7):

size_t is used to store sizes of data objects, and is guaranteed to be able to hold the size of any data object that the particular C implementation can create. This data type may be smaller (in number of bits), bigger or exactly the same as unsigned int.

Answer (score 2):

size_t type is a base unsigned integer type of
C/C++ language. It is the type of the result
returned by sizeof operator. The type's size is
chosen so that it could store the maximum size
of a theoretically possible array of any type. On a
32-bit system size_t will take 32 bits, on a 64-
bit one 64 bits. In other words, a variable of
size_t type can safely store a pointer. The
exception is pointers to class functions but this
is a special case. Although size_t can store a
pointer, it is better to use another unsigned
integer type uintptr_t for that purpose (its name
reflects its capability). The types size_t and
uintptr_t are synonyms. size_t type is
usually used for loop counters, array indexing
and address arithmetic.
The maximum possible value of size_t type is
constant SIZE_MAX .

Comment: `size_t` can store the size of any single object. A pointer can point to any byte of any object. You can have a system with, for example, a 64-bit address space that limits the size of any one object to 2**32-1 bytes. There is no guarantee that `size_t` and `uintptr_t` are the same type.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words size_t is platform and as well as implementation dependent whereas unsigned int is only platform dependent.