# Use `size_t` as the type for a counter

Tags: c++, size-t

Is it appropriate to use `size_t` instead of `int` or `unsigned` as the type for a counter?

The following code is grasped from *C++ Primer*.

```
size_t count_calls()
{
    static size_t ctr = 0;
    return ++ctr;
}

int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        cout << count_calls() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know that `size_t` is a good choice for size, array indexing, but what about when it comes to a plain counter? (as in the `count_calls` function.) Are there any difference?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t

Comment: possible duplicate of [unsigned int vs. size\_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t)

Comment: Edit: Irrelevant idea for this problem. In C++11 make use of auto and iterators to avoid making this decision in many cases.

Comment: A related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226483/where-to-draw-the-line-between-size-t-and-unsigned-int?lq=1

Comment: @NeilKirk in this case auto would derive a signed type. not what the user wants ...

Comment: @Alex You are right! It's not a good solution here. I was thinking of data structure iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size_t` is a type that is appropriate to count elements in an array and, therefore, in any array-based container. However, `size_t` is, conceptually, insufficient to count elements in a non-array-based container. (E.g. `size_t` is not guaranteed to be wide enough to count elements of `std::list`.) For this reason, in general case, it is inappropriate to use `size_t` as a generic counter type. And obvious example would be a segmented memory model, under which `size_t` might easily end up being relatively narrow compared to the capacity of the platform itself.

If you really want to find a generic type that is wide enough for most real-life cases, that would be `uintptr_t` perhaps. And again, the choice in this case is based on the fact that `uintptr_t` should be sufficiently wide to count anything that can fit in memory. However, for obvious reasons, it might still prove to be too small to count something more extensive.

I'd also add that using such generic types as `size_t` and `unitptr_t` as counters in application-specific code might be considered a questionable programming practice, since they don't convey any application-specific semantics. They are more memory-oriented than generic-counter-oriented.