# How do i change the value of a position of an array inside a struct that is allocated in shared memory(mmap) in c?

Tags: c, process, fork, shared-memory

I am trying to change the value of a position of an array inside a struct that is allocated in shared memory
I have this struct:

```
typedef struct Paths {
     int *path;
     int totalDistance;
     int quantity;
}Path;
```

And i have this algorithm:

```
void runAlgorithm(int** distances,int nCities, int executionTime, int nProcesses){
int size = nCities+2 * sizeof(int);
int protection = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
int visibility = MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED;
PtPath shmem = (PtPath)mmap(NULL, size, protection, visibility, 0, 0);
*shmem = createPath(nCities);
randomPath(shmem);
setPathTotalDistance(shmem, distances);
sem_unlink("job_ready");
sem_unlink("job_done");
sem_t *job_ready = sem_open("job_ready", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
sem_t *job_done = sem_open("job_done", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);

int *pids = (int*)calloc(nProcesses, sizeof(int));
Path path, shortestPath;

//Workers Processes
for(int i = 0 ; i < nProcesses ; i++){
    pids[i] = fork();
    if(pids[i] == 0){
        shortestPath = createPath(nCities);
        randomPath(&shortestPath); //inicializa caminho aleatorio
        setPathTotalDistance(&shortestPath, distances); //problema aqui 
        while(1){
            sem_wait(job_ready);                
            mutation(&shortestPath, distances);
            if(shortestPath.totalDistance < shmem->totalDistance){
                printPath(shmem);
                printPath(&shortestPath);
                copyPath(&shortestPath, shmem);
            }
            sem_post(job_done);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}

//Parent Process
int elapsed, terminate = 1;
time_t start = time(NULL), end;
printf("Elapsed time: \n");
while(terminate){
    end = time(NULL);
    elapsed = difftime(end,start);
    printElapsedTime(elapsed);
    if(elapsed >= executionTime)
        terminate = 0;
    else{
        sem_post(job_ready);
        sem_wait(job_done);
    }
}
printPath(shmem);
sem_close(job_ready);
sem_close(job_done);

// Kill worker processes
for (int i=0; i<nProcesses; i++) {
    printf("Killing %d\n", pids[i]);
    kill(pids[i], SIGKILL);
}
}
```

This is the code of createPath:

```
Path createPath(int quantity){
Path newPath;

if(quantity < 0)
    quantity = 0;
newPath.path = (int*)calloc(quantity, sizeof(int));
newPath.quantity = quantity;
newPath.totalDistance = 0;

return newPath;
}
```

And this is the copyPath code:

```
void copyPath(PtPath from, PtPath to){
for(int i = 0 ; i < from->quantity ; i++){
    //printf("posI: %d\n",to->path[i]);
    to->path[i] = from->path[i];
}
to->totalDistance = from->totalDistance;
to->quantity = from->quantity;
}
```

So my problem is i'm trying to copy the shortestPath to the shared memory and it copies nothing, but it does copy the totalDistance
What am i doing wrong and where?

Comment: What is the variable ```size``` in the second code block? Is it the ```sizeof(Paths)```?

Comment: The `path` field of your `struct Paths` is a **pointer**.  What memory do you think `shmem->path` points to?

Comment: If you want to use shared memory, then does this mean that you have another process(thread) tries to read this?

Comment: `shmem->path` is a pointer to an array of integer, not an array. I guess `size` is big enough for the struct and the array, so I guess after the allocation you should do `shmem->path = (int *)(shmem + 1)` which will put the array after the struct in the shared memory

Comment: @Stefan Becker If the shared memory is used in another process(thread), it won't be able to access ```path```. The OP has to clarify how he will use ```shmem```.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu that problem can simply be solved by removing `path` from the struct and use `int *path = (int *)(shmem + 1)` everywhere where `shmem` is accessed.

Comment: Of course another solution is to re-order the struct and put the array at the end, i.e. `{ int totalDistance; int size; int path[0]; }` and then allocate `sizeof(struct ...) + (size - 1)*sizeof(int)` of shared memory. Then the OP code should work unmodified.

Comment: @Stefan Becker If the shared memory is mapped tonother address, this method will immediately fail. Either the other process(thread) use ```mmap``` to load it (though it can't be done here) or its child process use ```mremap``` to change the size.

Comment: It is better to rewrite the structure to adjust to the requirements of shared memory than placing assumptions on how it is used.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu only if you forget to recalculate `path` after you re-mapped the shared memory.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu Size is equals to size of array(which is defined as number of cities)+2(because of the other 2 attribute i have on that struct) * sizeof(int)

Comment: No, you needed another ```sizeof(int*)``` for storing the pointer to the array.

Comment: @AndrewHenle i think it points like a normal array, i mean, when i call createPath() it allocates the memory that i need to use the array normally, so after that ill be able to use like the "newPath" ex.: shmem->path[0]

Comment: It is better to let ```size``` = ```sizeof(Paths) + /* sizeof array path*/```.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu ahhhh ok, thanks!!

Comment: And you add tag ```fork``` to this question, does this mean that the shared memory will be used by its child (from the way you setup shared memory, I guess you want to use it this way)?

Comment: @JiaHaoXu about the second comment you did, yes, i have 1 parent process, and x child processes, and i need to "share" a shortestPath with the parent

Comment: Better to edit your question and clarify all of them.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu i didnt post the whole code because i though it was too big to post it here

Comment: Just clarify what is ```size``` and how are you gonna to use the shared memory.

Comment: BTW, the sizeof the array path is not ```nCities```, it is ```nCities * sizeof(int)```.

Comment: Another advice: You may want to use thread instead of process so that you won't have to use shared memory any more and you don't have to worry about recording them and terminating threads one by one, simply ```exit_group(/* status_code */)``` will do the job. And it is more lightweight.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu i know that Jia, but this is a college project and in this version of the project i am not allowed, yet, to use threads

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use shared memory, then I recommand you to rewrite the structure since the address of the shared memory can be changed when `mmap`ing (not possible here) or `mremap`.

IMHO, it is always better to use offset inside shared memory than using pointer and assuming the address won't be changed, even if you can sure the address won't change now.

So:

```
struct Paths
{
    int totalDistance;
    int quantity;
    int path[0];
};
```

Since `path` is stored inlined with `Paths` continuously, there is no need for `int *path`.

When you allocate memory using `mmap`, the `size` should be `sizeof(Paths)` plus the size you need for storing `path`.

```
size_t size = sizeof(Paths) + /* Additional size needed for storing path */;
int protection = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
int visibility = MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED; 
PtPath shmem = (PtPath) mmap(NULL, size, protection, visibility, -1, 0);
```

When you accessing `path` from `Paths`, the compiler will use offset from the address of `Paths` to access it, so as long as you hold a valid pointer to a shared memory with valid `Paths`, you can access it no matter it is `mmap`ed or`mremap`ed.

Coping the data from `newPath` will be just:

```
Path newPath = createPath();
for(int i = 0 ; i < shmem->quantity ; i++)
    shmem->path[i] = newPath.path[i];
```

This method has a slight advantage over the method used in the question: it does not need any additional pointer, which might be useful if you allocate a lot of `Path`.

Now, it is better to use `void initializePath(Path*, int)` instead of `Path createPath(int)`:

```
void initializePath(Path *newPath, int quantity)
{
    if (quantity < 0)
        quantity = 0;
    newPath->quantity = quantity;
    newPath->totalDistance = 0;

    randomPath(shmem);       
    setPathTotalDistance(shmem, distances);
}
```

And you can have another function `Path* allocatePath(int)` to allocate `Path`:

```
Path* allocateSharedPath(int quantity)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(Paths) + quantity * sizeof(int);
    int protection = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
    int visibility = MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED; 

    Path *shmem = (Path*) mmap(NULL, size, protection, visibility, -1, 0);

    if (shmem == NULL)
        /* Handle failure */;

    return shmem;
}

Path* allocatePath(int quantity)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(Paths) + quantity * sizeof(int);

    Path *mem = (Path*) calloc(size, 1);

    if (mem == NULL)
        /* Handle failure */;

    return mem;
}
```

BTW, if you want to store something else between `quantity` and `path` or you want to store `path` before `Paths` you can do this:

```
struct Paths
{
    int totalDistance;
    int quantity;
    offset_t offset_to_path;
};
```

The `size` required to allocate is `sizeof(Paths) + /* Additional size needed for storing path */ + /* sizeof whatever else you need to store */`. When initializing, initialize `offset_to_path` to `pointer_to_path - pointer_to_Paths` so that you can access it by adding `offset_to_path` to the pointer to `Paths`.

Comment: Inside the struct, why is it better to use int path[0] rather than int *path?

Comment: Because you don't need pointer. This is actually a dynamically-sized struct.

Comment: The ```path``` is stored inlined with ```Paths```, they are continuous.

Comment: Ahhhh ok, thanks, i edited my post and added more code if it helps solving the problem.

Comment: i have another question, with the new changes of the struct, don't i have to change the way i allocate memory for the path array in my createPath()?

Comment: I think the answer is yes.

Comment: I never used size_t, is there any difference between int and size_t?

Comment: See [Difference between size_t and unsigned int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732319/difference-between-size-t-and-unsigned-int). Difference between ```size_t``` and ```int``` is similar, except that ```int``` is not intended to represent positive value only.

Comment: You should consider to search on ```stackoverflow``` (which you must can, since you can ask a  question) and`google``` before asking.