# Purpose of using (int) in the code below?

Tags: c++

```
n=b.size()    
n = max(n,(int)a.size());
```

where a and b are some user-Input strings and n is an integer. would anybody tell me why we use **(int)a.size()** and what is the purpose of using **(int)**.

Comment: What is the type of `n`?

Comment: the type of n is an integer.

Comment: if you take the cast out you probably get a compiler warning about signed/unsigned mismatch, casting the `size_t` to `int` would make that disappear.

Comment: `std::max` is a template. Take a look at the definition for it and you can probably figure it out. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that n is of type `int`, and your program will be something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string a ("Test string");
    string b ("Test two");

    int n = b.size()    ;
    n = max(n,(int)a.size());
    cout << "n : " << n ;

    return 0;
}
```

Now if you see the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) for the .size() method of the string class, you will see it returns value of type : `size_t`

> size_t is an unsigned integral type (the same as member type
>   string::size_type)
>   : as per [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/)

Now when we look at the [documentation for max()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) you can see it uses templating (you can read more about templating [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/)) what it essentially means is that you can use any [type](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) as parameter (int, float, etc..) but both the parameters need to be the same type.

Now since `n` was declared as an `int` when calling `max(n,x);`, `x` needs to be type of `n` which basically means `int` in our case.

Now this is the reason for using `(int)` before `a.size()`. What we are doing here is [type casting](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/typecasting/), since `a.size()` returns in type **size_t** which is different from **int** (You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732319/difference-between-size-t-and-unsigned-int)), we need to typecast the return value to **int** which can be done by `(int)a.size()`.

**SIDE NOTE**

```
 int n = max(b.size(),a.size());
 cout << "n : " << n << " \n";
```

would also work, since both are same type so no need to do type casting.