# Using an array of strings to implement a symbol table in C

Tags: c, symbol-table

I am trying to use an array of structs to create a symbol table. This is what I have so far, but I am having trouble allocating memory in the create function, is what I have so far correct?

I want something like this as my final result for arr 
{ {"sym1"; 1}, {"sym2"; 2}, {"sym3"; 3} }

```
struct str_id {
  char* s;
  int id;
}

struct symbol_table {
  int count;
  struct str_id** arr;
}

struct symbol_table *symbol_table_create(void) {
  struct symbol_table *stt = malloc(sizeof(struct symbol_table));
  stt->count = 1;
  stt->arr =  malloc(sizeof(struct str_id*) * stt->count);
  return stt;

}
```

Comment: `struct symbol_table { int count = 1; ... }` is illegal. You cannot initialize `struct` fields in the type declaration in C.

Comment: yes sorry, I fixed that. Is the rest fine?

Comment: how is it undefined if I set it to one in the create functions

Comment: oh I see what you mean, I forgot to do stt->count. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use descriptive names for identifiers, not cryptic short names (like `s` and `str_id`).
- [Avoid Systems Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) (i.e. naming or prefixing identifiers after their type or what-they-are as opposed to what-they-mean).

  - In your case, I assume `str_id` is an abbreviation for `struct_id` (or `string_id`) - which is a bad name because it's already immediately obvious that it's a `struct` (or contains a string).
  - It was popular right until the 1990s when programmers started using more powerful editors and IDEs that kept track of variable types - it just isn't needed today.
    *
- Always check if a heap allocation succeeded or failed by comparing `calloc` and `malloc`'s return values to `NULL`. This can be done with `if( some_pointer ) abort()`.

  - Don't use `assert( some_pointer )` because assertions are only enabled in debug builds, use `abort` instead as it signifies abnormal program termination compared to `exit`.
- Pass a `size_t` parameter so consumers can specify the size of the symbol table.
- Quantities of objects held in memory should be expressed as `size_t` (e.g. array indexers). [Never use `int` for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732319/difference-between-size-t-and-unsigned-int)!
- You need to put a semi-colon at the end of each `struct` definition.
- Are you sure you want an `array-of-pointers-to-structs` and not just an `array-of-structs`? In this case you can use inline structs and use a single allocation for the array, instead of allocating each member separately.
- Because you're performing custom allocation, you must also define a destructor function.

```
struct symbol_table_entry {
  char* symbolText;
  int   id;
};

struct symbol_table {
  size_t count;
  struct symbol_table_entry** entries;
};

struct symbol_table* create_symbol_table( size_t count ) {
    struct symbol_table* stt = malloc( sizeof(struct symbol_table) );
    if( !stt )
    {
        abort();
    }
    stt->count = count;
    stt->entries = calloc( count, sizeof(struct symbol_table_entry) );
    if( !stt->entries ) {
        free( stt );
        abort();
    }
    // Note that calloc will zero-initialize all entries of the array (which prevents debuggers showing garbage string contents) so we don't need to do it ourselves.
    return stt;
}

void destroy_symbol_table( struct symbol_table* stt, bool free_strings ) {
    if( stt->entries ) {
        if( free_strings ) {
            for( size_t i = 0; i < stt->count; i++ ) {
                free( stt->entries[i]->symbolText );
            }
        }
        free( stt->entries );
    }
    free( stt );
}
```

Comment: Wrong allocation with `stt->entries = calloc( count, sizeof(struct symbol_table_entry) );`.  Suggest `stt->entries = calloc( count, sizeof stt->entries[0]);` to avoid getting the type wrong.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you for the improvements, I've removed the guard around `free`. As for `sizeof`, I don't think using `sizeof( stt->entries[0] )` over `sizeof(struct symbol_table_entry)` presents much of an advantage in this situation though.

Comment: Dai, `sizeof(struct symbol_table_entry)` is the [wrong size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61036202/using-an-array-of-strings-to-implement-a-symbol-table-in-c/61036346?noredirect=1#comment107981784_61036346).  `sizeof(struct symbol_table_entry*)` would have been correct.  `sizeof( stt->entries[0] )` is more likely to be coded right (it avoids the original coding mistake of the wrong type, hence the advantage), easier to review and maintain.