# How do I properly pass the size of a vector to a function requiring an int?

Tags: c++, vector, size-t, function-parameter

I'm using a library with a function that has a parameter of type `int`.

I need to pass the size of the vector as the argument for this parameter.

I know I can get the the size of a vector using `someVector.size()`, but this returns the type `size_t`.

I know I can cast the `size_t` to an `int`: e.g. `static_cast<int>(someVector.size())`.  However, casting might cause problems if `someVector.size()` exceeds the max value of `int`.

What's the proper way to pass the size of a vector to a function requiring a parameter of type `int`?

Comment: Clearly your library function cannot handle arrays larger than the greatest value representable by `int`, so don't pass it any arrays that are larger.

Comment: What library are you using? You might need to look into that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "safe" way to pass a `std::size_t` to a function accepting `int` (whenever the `size_t` is larger than the maximal representable `int` you're in trouble). You can however test if passing is safe:

```
if(v.size() < std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) // need to #include <limits> 
{
    // safe to pass
}
else
{
    // not safe, throw error/exit/print something
}
```

The comparison is always safe, provided the `int` is positive.

Comment: it probably makes sense to overload the original function with a size_t version and put this code there

Comment: @user3528438 not sure I understand, you mean overload the OP function that takes an `int`?

Comment: overload it or wrap around it

Comment: @user3528438 Ah ok I see. Yes, indeed, can write a wrapper or overload. The only issue may be eventual ambiguities if you pass some integral type for which the conversion to `size_t` or `int` is equally good (e.g. on my machine a `unsigned long long`).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the library documentation for solutions, they might accept values of type `unsigned int` which is pretty similar to `size_t`. Here is another post that might help: [unsigned int vs. size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t).