# C data type conversion

Tags: c

Can I be sure that data conversion always succeeds? If I have an `int` and I use `mmap(2)`, is the `int` converted to `off_t` and `size_t`? Why are there all those different sizes? And are there conversion function?

Comment: You can definitely not be sure that conversions always succeed. For example, conversions from integer types to floating-point types and from floating-point to integer result in undefined behavior if the values cannot be represented in the new type.

Comment: Can you be sure that conversions always succeed, in general? No. And in your specific example, `off_t` isn't even standard C, it's POSIX. Although `size_t` and `int` are both guaranteed to be at least 16-bits.

Comment: Also, by _"Why are there all those different sizes?"_, what do you mean? Do you mean why are different types not all the same size, or why are there different types, or...?

Comment: Of interest: https://github.com/git/git/commit/aafa5df0df39036c6500846acd3db5b75d264a3b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the usage of the mmap function you are doing since mmap  returns a pointer.

- Regarding conversion you can basically convert any variable to anything using a cast, however it is your responsibility to verify that this will work for example:

  ```
  int i;
  double d;    
  d = 42.3;
  i = (int)d;
  printf("i = %d", i);
  ```

Output will be 42, without the cast `(int)` some compilers would probably complain and warn you that you will lose floating precision.

- About the why of all these different sizes, first thing `size_t` is meant to represent a size so you can grossly think of it as an `unsigned int`, regarding why not use a `unsigned int` rather than a typedef'ed "size_t", see this post [unsigned int vs size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/131833/2308258).