# How can I send a pointer to element in array from type `void*`?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void

given the following array (for example):

```
int arr[6] = {1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5, 6};
```

If I send it to function with the following decleration:

```
int func(void* array, int n);
```

**How can I send from `func` to the following function:**

```
int f(void* element);
```

**address for some element in the array?**

I tried to do something like that: `f(array + i);` (in order to send `&array[i]`) , but I get the following error:

> pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic

So , how can I do it?

Comment: Is `func` only called with `int` arrays, or can the `array` argument to `func` be of a different type?

Comment: Does `func` know the type of `arr` or not? If not, then you are probably out of luck. You'd have to pass along the item size in that case.

Comment: Cast it to `int*` first. `f((int*)array + i)`

Comment: @DanielPryden No , `array` is not only `int` array .

Comment: @Lundin So I need to pass additional parameter `int size_` that will describe the size of any element in the array?

Comment: @Software_t Yeah that's usually how it is done in traditional generic C programming. Base address, number of items, item size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepting, for whatever reason, that you can't write

```
int func(int* array, int n);
```

you need to change the type of `array` back to something on which *pointer arithmetic* is valid:

```
int* real_array = (int*)array;
```

Then you can use the tractable notation `real_array[i]` to access elements.

If you want to keep `func` generic though in the sense that you don't know the type, you'd have to pass an element size along with the array size:

```
int func(void* array, int/*ToDo - use size_t here too*/ n, size_t element_size)
```

then you could use

```
f((const char*)array + i * element_size)
```

although I fear that is merely pushing the problem of resolving the genericity further down the call stack.

Comment: Thank you about your answer, it's clarifies the topic! :)

Answer (score 2):

If `func` needs to be able to work with arrays of different types, then you'll need to add a new `size_t` argument to `func` to tell it the size of the array items. Otherwise, something like `array[1]` is ill-defined: do you mean `array + 4 bytes`, `array + 8 bytes`, `array + 1 byte`, or something else?

If you have an item size parameter, you can cast `array` to a `char*` and offset by `i * item_size` to get a pointer to the `i`th element.

(Note that your item size parameter should probably be `size_t` rather than `int`.)

Comment: The type of this argument must be `size_t` ? It's can't be `int`?

Comment: @Software_t: The difference between two `void*` can always be represented by `size_t`, but is not guaranteed to be representable by `int`. So `size_t` is more correct.

Comment: Which types can do errors if I will define it as `int`? (Namely , in which cases it's may fail if I will define it as `int`?)

Comment: If the types you're working with are all small then there shouldn't be a difference in practice. But pretty much *any* time you're working with a value that semantically *means* the "size" of something, it should be `size_t`. That's what `size_t` is *for*, and that's why the `sizeof` operator is defined to return `size_t` and not `int`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t for further discussion of the difference between `size_t` and `int`. Note also that `size_t` is guaranteed to be unsigned, and `int` is AFAIK guaranteed to be signed, so that's an obvious difference right off the bat.

Comment: It fails when I pass it a array of my pictures of earth from space, each a size of 16GB. It fails whenever the size of the array elements can't be represented as int. So you probably never ever see it fail. But do write correct code and use `size_t`.

Comment: "int is AFAIK guaranteed to be signed" --> not when used in a bit-field.  Use `signed int` to insure sign-ness there.