# using auto when the infered type is not exactly what I want

Tags: c++, auto

I want to loop over (unsigned) integers from 0 to 100. For that I have 2 options - use `size_t`, or `auto`:

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#ifndef use_auto
#include <cstddef>
#endif

int main(){
#ifdef use_auto
#ifdef suffix
  constexpr auto num = 1;
#else
  constexpr auto num = 1ul;
#endif
  for (auto i = 0; i < num; i++){
    std::cout << "auto\n";
  }
#else 
  constexpr size_t num = 1;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++){
    std::cout << "explicit type\n";
  }
#endif
  std::cout << typeid(num).name() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

```bash
$ g++ bla.cpp && ./a.out | c++filt -t
explicit type
unsigned long
$ g++ bla.cpp -Duse_auto -Dsuffix && ./a.out | c++filt -t
auto
int
$ g++ bla.cpp -Duse_auto && ./a.out | c++filt -t
auto
unsigned long
```

Now, the branch defined under "use_auto" + "suffix" could be considered the best, as it:

1. uses auto
2. gets the correct type due to using integer literal

My question is more of a "best practice". For me, `size_t` seems clearer than `auto num = 1ul`, but I do like using auto as much as possible, for readablity and maintainanability.

Is there a concrete guideline on what's best to use here, or is this opinion based?

Comment: Why `size_t` instead of plain `unsigned`?

Comment: both would do, but the question still stands, and also - I just read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295225/3512538 that `size_t` is preferable

Comment: I think how much you use `auto`  is a matter of opinion or style, but these are not necessarily going to be the same thing.

Comment: The argument that size_t is "always large enough" doesn't weigh that much if you only need values between 0 and 100. :-)  But anyway, with C++23 you get `auto i = 0uz` to get a `size_t` literal. So yet another option.

Comment: c++23 is far from the c++14 I'm using :( but it's nice to know I'll be able to use that eventually

Comment: You're missing another: `auto num = std::size_t{1};`! This looks a bit strange, yet respect the "[almost always auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)" moto.

Answer (score 2):

The suffix `ul` makes the literal a `unsigned long`, you want it to be `size_t`.

`size_t` may **or may not** be `unsigned long`. There is no guarantee for it and I expect `size_t` to actually be `unsigned int` on 32-bit platforms.

Using the suffix would give you the wrong type, at least on some platforms, so it's not portable.

Either use `size_t num = ...` or, if you absolutely must use `auto`, use `auto num = static_cast<size_t>(...)`.

Or use `size_t num{...};` - this prevents any narrowing conversions when the literal would not fit into the type. If the value does not fit, you'll get a compile-time error

```
// Error on 32-bit platforms, works on 64-bit platforms.
std::size_t num{9999999999};
```

Which one is more readable is up to you / your colleagues.

Apparently there will be a `zu` suffix for `size_t` [in C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), maybe you can use that already.